# Proof Technique and Factorials

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I need to prove that $\;n!+m$ is divisible by $m$ for all integers $n \ge 2$ and $1 \le m \le n$.

Comment: Hint: what is your definition of factorial?

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

- express $n!$ knowing $1\leq m\leq n$, $\;n \geq 2$. You'll find that indeed, $m \mid n!$

  - To see this concretely, let's try an example.
  - Suppose $n = 4$. We know $1 \leq m \leq n$. So $m$ must be one of the
    factors in $n! = 4 \cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1$. Hence $m \mid n!$
  - It doesn't matter how large $n$ is, so long as $n$ greater than or
    equal to 2, and $m$ is a positive integer less than or equal to $n$: Then one factor in $n!$ must be $m$.
- And we know, trivially, $m\mid m$.

Then it follows from the fact that if $a\mid b$ and $a \mid c$, then $a\mid (b + c)$,

and conclude that $m$ divides $n! + m$.